# need add-in to make decision tree from LibreOffice Calc

Tags: add-in, decision-tree, libreoffice-calc

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 version. Kindly suggest me **add-in** for LibreOffice Calc through which I able to built decision tree. For example:
TreePlan is an Excel add-in that allows you to build decision trees in Excel.
Same like **TreePlan** add-in I need for LibreOffice Calc and please tell with complete method to follow it such as from where I get it and how to use it?
How can I reach it?